# Why is there no console output from my docker container?

Tags: python, docker

I have an application that consists of a docker container with a redis instance, another docker container with a rabbitmq server, and a third container in which I'm trying to start a number of celery workers that can interact with the redis and rabbitmq containers. I'm starting and stopping these workers via a rest api, and have checked that I'm able to do this on my host machine. However, after moving the setup to docker, it seems the workers are not behaving as expected. Whereas on my host machine (windows 10) I was able to see the reply from the rest api and console output from the workers, I can only see the response from the rest api (a log message) and no console output. It also seems that the workers are not accessing the redis and rabbitmq instances.

My docker container is built from a python3.6 (linux) base image. I have checked that everything is installed correctly, and there are no error logs. I build the image with the following dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6

WORKDIR /opt

# create a virtual environment and add it to PATH so that it is applied for 
# all future RUN and CMD calls
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/opt/venv
RUN python3 -m venv $VIRTUAL_ENV
ENV PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"

# install msodbcsql17
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y curl apt-transport-https gnupg2 \
    && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - 
\
    && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/9/prod.list > 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17 mssql-tools


# Install Mono for pythonnet.
RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install --yes \
    dirmngr \
    clang \
    gnupg \
    ca-certificates \
    # Dependency for pyodbc.
    unixodbc-dev \
    && apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 
    3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF \
    && echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian 
    stretch/snapshots/5.20 main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official- 
    stable.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install --yes \
   
    mono-devel=5.20\* \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY requirements.txt .
COPY src ./src
COPY setup.py ./setup.py
COPY config.json ./config.json
COPY Utility.dll ./Utility.dll
COPY settings_docker.ini ./settings.ini
COPY config.json ./config.json
COPY sql_config.json ./sql_config.json

RUN python3 -m venv $VIRTUAL_ENV \
# From here on, use virtual env's python.
&& venv/bin/pip install --upgrade pip \
&& venv/bin/pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip setuptools wheel \

&& venv/bin/pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt \
# Dependency for pythonnet.
&& venv/bin/pip install --no-cache-dir pycparser \
&& venv/bin/pip install -U  --no-cache-dir "pythonnet==2.5.1" \
# && python -m pip install --no-cache-dir "pyodbc==4.0.25" "pythonnet==2.5.1"

EXPOSE 8081

cmd python src/celery_artifacts/docker_workers/worker_app.py
```

And then run it with this command:

```
docker run --name app -p 8081:8081 app
```

I then attach the container to the same bridge network as the other 2:

```
docker network connect my_network app
```

Is there a way to see the same console output from my container as the one on the host?

Comment: Please report the commands which you are using.

Comment: ...yes...how are you running the container, and where are you expecting the output to show up?

Comment: `docker ps` what does it show?

Comment: @Sachith Muhandiram docker ps shows this for the container: ID: b151353e86c6   Image: app                   Command: "/bin/sh -c 'python …"   Created: About a minute ago   status: Up About a minute  ports: 0.0.0.0:8081->8081/tcp

Comment: @CryptoFool edited the question to include the dockerfile and run command. I'm expecting the output to show up either in docker desktop or the terminal session from which I run the container. I even tried accessing the container and running the script that starts the workers via bash, and still got no output.

Comment: What does `docker logs app` show you?  If you log into the container via a Bash shell, and when you run the script manually, you get no output, then something is going on with the script itself.  At that point, there is no difference between being in a Docker container and being at a Bash prompt in a VM or on bare metal.  I would suggest that you start at the very top of your script and add some `print` statements to see that the script is actually running and can produce some sort of output.

Comment: @CryptoFool the only thing it shows is that the api call went through: 172.17.0.1 - - [24/Mar/2021 15:01:11] "POST /worker_api/manage_workers/start HTTP/1.1" 200 -
I'm using the exact same flask settings and logger locally and seeing all my output on the console, but in the container only the above.

Comment: As an aside, why are you using a virtual environment in a Docker container?  There's really no reason to do this.  This only adds unnecessary complication, IMO.

Comment: @CryptoFool I'm aware of this but I couldn't keep track of where my dependencies were being installed without it, so I chose the "if it ain't broken don't fix it approach"

Comment: Ok, so if I have it right, then your app is running under Flask.  There is then something different about your configuration between the two environments.  Docker in and of itself should not be causing any difference in behavior as it's just the same old Linux we know and love.

Comment: Ok Boris, I guess that makes sense. - I wish I could think of something more to tell you to help you out.  I've not got a ton of experience with Docker, but everything I've done suggests that it is just Linux, and that a difference in behavior should always be due to the difference in the way you've built or configured the container rather than some issue inherent to Docker.  The one place Docker IS fairly different, of course, is in network setup, but you seem to be past that as your Flask server is accepting requests per the log output.  Best of luck!

Comment: @CryptoFool thanks! I think the issue might be with the logging handler, for which I have the following configuration:     "handlers": {
        "console": {
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "formatter": "detailed",
            "level": "DEBUG",
        } - it might be the case that these settings are incompatible with linux

Comment: That makes sense.  You might add some straight `print` statements to confirm that your code is running and just isn't logging correctly.